# Duplicating existing cakephp app for development

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I need to make a development version of a cakePHP app with its own db so that a developer can work on it without disturbing the current users.

I thought it would be simple, I just copied the entire director /project to /project_dev and then copied the DB "project_db" to "project_db_dev". Then I went into /project_dev/config/database.php and changed the db to "project_db_dev".

When I went to see what I had done, I saw the app was still connecting to the same db, as if I'd changed nothing. I realized that the original folder name was referenced in /app/webroot/.htaccess so do I need to find/replace all instances of that folder name?

What steps should I follow to duplicate an existing cakePHP app?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to use something like Git to version control and make either a fork of the repository or a new dev branch. Presumably the dev version of the app is being accessed differently to the main one (e.g. a different URL) so in bootstrap you could switch to a different Database connection. It would then make it easier to update the production app with the dev changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup some kind of development lifecycle.

Generally speaking the developer shouldn't be doing any development on the server. The best way to handle it is locally using a stack of some kind such as Lamp (Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP) switch out linux with other OS's. There are multiple cloud solution to these environments to such as Koding.com

Using something like Git for version control the developer can develop locally then push the code through to the server after is being thoroughly tested locally or on a dev server or some kind.

Keeping Dev work and Live work away from each other is key.

Answer (score 1):

Could do with a bit more information.

If both databases are hosted on the same server and you have permission to access them both with the same user then all you have to do is change the name of the database in your database.php

If not you will also have to update the IP and any other additional settings port etc.

If you are still having troubles email me simpsond1988@gmail.com